# Deducible implies satisfiable (first order logic)

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let $\sigma$ be an $L$-sentence and $\Sigma$ an $L$-theory. Then, if $\Sigma$ deduces $\sigma$, it also satisfies it.
I've tried proving this by induction on the formal proof for $\sigma$ from $\Sigma$ but it is fairly confusing, is there any easier way to prove this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, induction on proof complexity is the only way to go - remember that deducibility itself is defined recursively, so it's hard to see how to analyze it without using induction.

The key point to note is that *the proof rules are truth preserving*. For instance, the last step in a minimal counterexample (= a proof $\pi$ whose conclusion is not entailed semantically, and has the least length among such) cannot be $\wedge$-introduction: if $\Sigma\models a$ and $\Sigma\models b$ then $\Sigma\models a\wedge b$ (just check the $\wedge$ clause in the definition of $\models$), so if $p=a\wedge b$ is $\Sigma$-provable but not $\Sigma$-entailed then either $a$ or $b$ would also have the same property via a shorter proof (indeed, a proper subproof of $\pi$).

You'll continue like this, and show that for every proof rule, that rule can't be the last step in a minimal counterexample. That shows that indeed $\Sigma\vdash p\implies\Sigma\models p$.

Comment: Why prove the contrapositive rather than the direct statement?

Comment: @DerekElkins No particular reason, I have found that a few people find it somewhat easier to conceptualize this way.